# How is volume defined and measured in nuclear physics, in particular regarding the Sun’s core?

Tags: nuclear-physics, sun, fusion, volume

The Sun’s core is, from the micro/quantum perspective (from what I've read) the constantly moving phenomena of nuclear fusion (as the Earth is mostly the constantly moving phenomena of stable atoms with electron orbits/clouds and their interconnections). So how can “volume”, “space” and “distance” be put in the equivalent cross-referential contexts (that it seems must apply to the quantum/micro as well as macro size levels of things) for say, some lead on Earth vs. the Sun’s core?  Both with respect to definition and measurement.

Note I have looked up the physics definitions of the "meter" (cubed), but I had trouble making sense of it in terms of a nuclear fusion incarnation.

Comment: I have voted to close because to answer the question one has to write at least an article. The fusion reactions   happening in the solar core are  complicated, and the thermodynamic changes due to these reactions have to be estimated in order to answer the volume and meter questions .   see the complexity here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_core

Comment: @annav rushing to close with that rationale for it, really? If you understand the question and answer well enough to vote to close it, can you please then give me just the high level answer to this quite a straightforward question? Because I often see good answers here of several paragraphs. Or please link or copy-paste specific parts of an article that answer my specific question at the high level rather than just say it’s “complicated” and link to the Wikipedia article on the Sun’s core, which upon me reading is what lead to my confusion that sparked my question to begin with.

Comment: Your specific question " how is  volume defined and  measured in nuclear physics" has no answer in nuclear physics which deals with quantum mechanical models and probabilities and does not use the concept of volume .

Comment: In order to understand how the dimensions of the core  are estimated one has to go to the references in the article of wiki . example https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0651 , just reading the abstract one can see the complexity of estimating anything that has to do with the interior of the sun.

Answer (score 2):

> How is volume defined and measured in nuclear physics, in particular regarding the Sun’s core ?

Since we don't attempt to define the size of things like the Sun's core or the Earth's core down to the sub-millimetre level (indeed, I doubt if their size is even defined to within a precision of $100$ kilometres), I think the answer is "the same way as for any other macroscopic object". If you are happy estimating the volume of your bath or your car's fuel tank, the same techniques can be used to estimate the volume of the Sun's core.

Comment: [Looks skeptically at his late father-in-law's fabric tape measure...]

Comment: Hey, I'm not referring to sub-millimeter sizes as the aggregate computed measurement, but to measuring the volume of the Sun’s core, which according to Wikipedia has a volume of 7.6 billion cubic km, which is not small nor sub-millimeter. Additionally, the official physics definition of the ‘meter’ is defined in accordance with the 'second' and rooted in measuring oscillations in an atom (or individual wavelengths of light), which is a much smaller level of base necessary measurement than even a millimeter, so seems we must be definitionally rooted in measuring the extremely small.

Comment: @lars706 Then I think you need to rephrase your question to clarify what you mean by "equivalent cross-referential contexts" and "a nuclear fusion incarnation", since I obviously do not understand your question, and others have voted to close it without even attempting an answer. I fail to see what you find confusing about an estimated volume of 7.6 billion cubic km or the modern definition of the metre.

Comment: @gandalf61 then please just give me the high-level overview of the technique/process used to measure and conclude that the Sun's core has a volume of 7.6 billion cubic km, and then briefly explain how that's rooted in the official physics definition of the meter(cubed). I would appreciate that. Reasonable?

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for understanding the spirit of my question and confusion…and for putting it in a clever/funny way :)

Comment: @lars706 If your real question is "how do we know that the Sun's core has a volume of 7.6 billion cubic km ?" then you need to post that clearly and simply as a new question, and leave out all the stuff about "equivalent cross-referential contexts" and "nuclear fusion incarnation" which has led to this question being closed for lack of clarity.

Comment: @lars706: Heh, thanks. But I also have a physics suggestion. Your question would benefit from ignoring quantum mechanics and instead focussing on general relativity, in which distance and volume along space-like slices certainly does make sense.

Comment: @LeeMosher yes I think that is the crux of my issue, thanks. I had been reading a lot on general relativity and understanding and connecting with it (at the basic and not deep math level), but then when coming at things from a quantum/nuclear perspective on phenomena of the big/celestial, things can get logically tricky. I think I just need to take some more days/weeks to actually understand the math of the GR tensor equations, and then refer back to my own questions about how macro/celestial star mass can be understood as built up from the particle level hyper-energetic phenomena.